# setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth does not strech iAD to full landscape

Tags: ios, objective-c, iad

I have created an app that only runs in landscape mode. I am attempting to make it so that the add will stretch across a screen in landscape. Recent questions state that

```
[self.bannerView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin];
```

should give me the desired effect, but this is not the case. I create the banner programmatically. The code for my banner is

```
    //allocate add banner
self.bannerView = [[ADBannerView alloc]initWithAdType:ADAdTypeBanner];
[self.bannerView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin];

//_bannerView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape;

/*CGRect contentFrame = self.view.bounds;
CGRect bannerFrame = _bannerView.frame;
contentFrame.size.height -= _bannerView.frame.size.height;
bannerFrame.origin.y = contentFrame.size.height;

self.bannerView.frame = bannerFrame;*/


[self.view addSubview:self.bannerView];
```

All the delegate methods are included later in the project.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it by forcing the iAD to be the width of the view

```
    //allocate add banner
self.bannerView = [[ADBannerView alloc]initWithAdType:ADAdTypeBanner];
[self.bannerView setAlpha:0];
[self.bannerView setDelegate:self];

//_bannerView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape;
[self.bannerView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];




CGRect contentFrame = self.view.bounds;
CGRect bannerFrame = _bannerView.frame;
bannerFrame.size.width = contentFrame.size.width;
self.bannerView.frame = bannerFrame;
bannerFrame = _bannerView.frame;
contentFrame.size.height -= _bannerView.frame.size.height;
bannerFrame.origin.y = contentFrame.size.height;
self.bannerView.frame = bannerFrame;


[self.view addSubview:self.bannerView];
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create the object if you set the width property to the width of the screen it will work. Example:

```
iAds_View = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, screen_Width, iAds_View.frame.size.height)];
```